# Sharepoint - filter a calculated column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a "Calculated" column of date.

I would like to know if there is any chance to filter data by this column?
I'm fetching data with REST API and when I try to filter data by "Calculated" column, I'm getting error.

There is any way to filter List by "Calculated" column?

Answer (score 0):

We can't use filter or orderby on Calculated fields in REST method in SharePoint 2013 as it is also not supported in query filter expression.

In this case you have to write a CAML query and make a POST request.

Reference: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200539/is-possible-to-make-filter-on-calculated-column.